# How to do a custom range for a QSpinBox

Tags: qt, qspinbox

Hi first time posting here.  I searched and found how re-implementing the QSpinBox class allows for custom uses.  However I am not sure if my needs are addressed in as much as what I found by re-implementing the validate method.

I need a custom range that excludes a zero value in the range of values.  The spinner is used for selecting zoom ratio for a loaded image.  The initial range at design time is -25 to 10.  That range could change depending on the dimensions of the image.  Nevertheless, I have to be able to "skip" zero for a desired zoom factor.   For example, the range would have to always be going from -1 to 1 or vice-versa.

Comment: It seems like the only way to skip some values is reimplementing `stepBy` function.

Comment: It seems that I can call stepBy directly rather than through re-implementing.  I am going to use that along with the suggestion from @headsvk

Comment: I mean "the only right way" :) `QAbstractSpinBox` provides `stepBy` virtual function exactly for that goals like you have.

Comment: Indeed!  That's why I'm going to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're listening to `QSpinbox::valueChanged(int i)` signal, there you can do something like this:

```
void zoomImage(int i) {
   if (i == 0) {
      if (lastValue < 0)      //if sliding from negative values
         spinBox->setValue(1);
      else
         spinBox->setValue(-1);

      return;                  //skip processing for 0
   }
   else
      lastValue = i;           //save last state to a class variable

   //processing...
}
```

EDIT: `int lastValue` is used for storing the position of slider before it hits 0 in order to determine if the user slides to negative or positive values

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Is the example you posted a slot?  It has the same name and signature as the signal valueChanged(int i).  I am using the signal and called a slot (zoomImage(int)) from it.  This may be better (or at least simpler) than re-implementing QSpinBox methods.  Need to capture/cache a means for lastValue

Comment: yeah sure, it's a slot.. you need to know somehow, which direction the user moved the slider in order to skip 0 to -1 or 1, so I used lastValue to remember the last position of the slider before it can reach 0

Comment: Have a solution I think but can't post for a while due to my place in the SO caste system.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have worked:

```
void MainWindow::zoomImage(int ctlValue)
{
   if(ctlValue == 0)
   {
     if(zoomLastValue < 0)
        ui->sbScaleImage->stepBy(1);
     else
        ui->sbScaleImage->stepBy(-1);
   }

   zoomLastValue = ui->sbScaleImage->value();
}
```

Apologies if I screwed up the formatting.